# Allow User to add new tags in-between tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, semantic-ui

I want to make it something where the user can move tags around and the user can add new tags in-between tags.

A cursor would appear if the user clicks between two tags for adding more tags.

I had done this Yet -> [See On Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dbr26njq/60).

```
<input type="button" id="setValues" value="Set Values" />
<input type="button" id="clearValues" value="Clear Values" />

<div class="ui fluid selection search dropdown multiple sortable">
  <input name="tags" type="hidden">

  <div class="default text">Select</div>
  <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="item" data-value="angular">Angular</div>
    <div class="item" data-value="css">CSS</div>
    <div class="item" data-value="design">Graphic Design</div>
    <div class="item" data-value="ember">Ember</div>
    <div class="item" data-value="html">HTML</div>
    <div class="item" data-value="ia">Information Architecture</div>
    <div class="item" data-value="javascript">Javascript</div>
    <div class="item" data-value="mech">Mechanical Engineering</div>
    <div class="item" data-value="meteor">Meteor</div>
    <div class="item" data-value="node">NodeJS</div>
    <div class="item" data-value="plumbing">Plumbing</div>
    <div class="item" data-value="python">Python</div>
    <div class="item" data-value="rails">Rails</div>
    <div class="item" data-value="react">React</div>
    <div class="item" data-value="repair">Kitchen Repair</div>
    <div class="item" data-value="ruby">Ruby</div>
    <div class="item" data-value="ui">UI Design</div>
    <div class="item" data-value="ux">User Experience</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown({
        onChange: function (value, text, $selectedItem) {
            console.log(value);
        },
        forceSelection: false, 
        selectOnKeydown: false, 
        showOnFocus: false,
        on: "hover" 
    });
});

$('#clearValues').click(function() {
    $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown("clear");
});

$('#setValues').click(function() {
    $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown("set selected", [
        "angular", "css", "design", "ember", "html", "ia", "javascript",
        "mech", "meteor", "node", "plumbing", "python", "rails", "react",
        "repair", "ruby", "ui", "ux"
    ]);
});
$(".sortable").sortable({
    revert: true
});
```

However, I was not able to complete the rest.

I want exactly the same thing happening in image below.

[image]

Comment: since it's sortable, you can drag element forward and your cursor stays behind. I was able to input between two tags from your fiddle

Comment: Sir, I know it is sortable but i need to add tags between the tags

Comment: This is a functionality provided by semantic library. In order to do what you want you'll have to fully understand the source code of this library. It's not as simple as it may seem. If you're willing to try, good luck. But I don't think this is a job for a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: if you move a tag after the cursor ... you can insert between tag

Comment: I am beeng lazy to create a project and test on browser. But I would code something like this. Explanation: inspecting an element I see all tags have a class "ui label" I would click that "a" tag and add before that a tag an input with class ".input.search.ui-sortable-handle". if you inspect cursor it is an input with this class. 
     $( ".ui.label" ).click(function() {
         console.log("test");
           $( "this" ).before( $('<input class="search ui-sortable-handle" autocomplete="off" tabindex="0">') );

        });